# Desktop dual-boot: Full resource availability

Tags: linux, operating-system, boot

There are a couple of desktops in my office on Windows which are temporarily not being used. I would like to use them on Linux for a proof of concept exercise. I would need to release the desktops with Windows anytime when the need arises. I plan to have a dual-boot OS (Linux & Windows) on them, so that it is easier to release them whenever a need arises.

With dual boot, when I'm using the desktops on Linux for the PoC, will the full system capacity (CPU, memory, storage) be available or the system resources get hard partitioned and a portion of it is never available?

Answer (score 0):

The operating system that is currently running will always have full access to the machine. "Dual booting" is not something recognized by the machine itself. It's just a term to describe a particular setup.